# Conformal mappings and inverse function theorem relationship

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Suppose $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is a conformal mapping at $z_0$, meaning it is analytic in a neighborhood of $z_0$ and $f'(z_0) \neq 0$.

Then in a sufficiently small neighbourhood $U$ of $z_0$, the image $f(U)$ will be a region which is

1. centered at $f(z_0)$
2. $f(U)$ has size approximately equal to $|f'(z_0)|$
3. $f(U)$ will be approximately rotation of $U$ by the argument of $f'(z_0)$

The inverse function theorem says: Let $f: R^2 \to R^2$ be $C^1$ on some open set of $a$ and $det Jf(a) \neq 0$. Then there is some open set $V$ containing $a$ and an open $W$ containing $f(a)$ such that $f : V \to W$ has an inverse $f^{-1}: W \to V$ which is $C^1$ for all $y \in W$. Furthermore, $J(f^{-1})(y) = [(Jf)(f^{-1}(y))]^{-1}$ as matrices.

I have a few questions about the relationship between conformal mappings and the inverse function theorem.

1. for the conformal mapping part, is the "sufficiently small neighbourhood $U$" associated with the neighbour $V$ as in the inverse theorem function? What I mean is consider a conformal $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ as a mapping from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, then $f$ satisfies the inverse theorem function conditions and has some neighbour $V$ which maps 1-1 etc... Now consider $V$ as a region in $\mathbb{C}$, does $f(V)$ have the nice properties listed as 1., 2.,3. above?
2. Does the $W$ in the inverse function theorem have size equal to the determinant of the Jacobian?

Comment: Your items 1, 2, and 3 are unclear as written. By a "region $G$ centered at $z$" do you simply mean $z\in G$? What do you mean by "size"? Item 3 is clear but wrong.

Comment: @MoisheKohan My question was based on the 3rd PSET, problem 1.6.1 of  https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-18-008-calculus-revisited-complex-variables-differential-equations-and-linear-algebra-fall-2011/study-materials/ . I just reread the solution and I think what they meant was that the area of the image $f(U)$ is approximately $|f'(z_0)|$ as $U$ becomes smaller. Similarly $f(U)$ is approximately a rotation by the argument $f'(z_0)$